# (error) read-only small data overflow in GHS compiler

Tags: linker-errors, greenhills

I'm using GHS compiler. I get this error message when trying to build my project.

[Click to see: elxr Linker error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsiqi.png)

```
[elxr] (error) read-only small data overflow: (signed) didn't fit in 16 bits while performing relocation.
```

**Update:**
The output of MULTI IDE after adding # and -v

```
[elxr] (warning) section .NOINIT_RAM_UNSPECIFIED from Port_Ram.o isn't included by the section map;
  appending after last section.
  add to section map or use -append to append without warning

[elxr] (warning) section .PORT_CFG_DATA_UNSPECIFIED from Port_PBcfg.o isn't included by the section map;
  appending after last section.
  add to section map or use -append to append without warning

[elxr] (warning) section .PORT_CFG_DBTOC_UNSPECIFIED from Port_PBcfg.o isn't included by the section map;
  appending after last section.
  add to section map or use -append to append without warning

[elxr] (warning) section .CONST_ROM_UNSPECIFIED from Port_Hardware.o isn't included by the section map;
  appending after last section.
  add to section map or use -append to append without warning

[elxr] (warning) section .PORT_PUBLIC_CODE_ROM from Port.o isn't included by the section map;
  appending after last section.
  add to section map or use -append to append without warning

[elxr] (warning) section .PORT_PRIVATE_CODE_ROM from Port.o isn't included by the section map;
  appending after last section.
  add to section map or use -append to append without warning

 Cleaning output\example
Building output\example
Assembling dr7f701587_startup.850 because dr7f701587_startup.o does not exist
Compiling App_PORT_F1K_Sample.c because App_PORT_F1K_Sample.o does not exist
Compiling Dem.c because Dem.o does not exist
Compiling Port.c because Port.o does not exist
Compiling Port_Hardware.c because Port_Hardware.o does not exist
Compiling Port_PBcfg.c because Port_PBcfg.o does not exist
Compiling Port_Ram.c because Port_Ram.o does not exist
Compiling Port_Version.c because Port_Version.o does not exist
Output from Assembling dr7f701587_startup.850:
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ecom800.exe --option=70 -Z848 -Z752 -X722 -X682 -X735 -X780 \
        -Z1715 -X1165 --c --gnu=safe -Z1835 --diag_warning=223 \
        --diag_warning=1547,1791 -Z1840 --config \
        t,t,l,,2,4,4,8,4,2,4,4,8,4,8,32,4,8,8,4,8,8,-1,f,f,-1,i,ui,1,f,t,1,1,8,1,8,72,4,6,f,3,0,0 \
        --option=30 --option=40 --option=147 --gnu_version=40300 -$ -X70 \
        -X1532 -X1602 -X540 --option=124 --alternative_tokens \
        --diag_remark=667,1546 --pragma_diag_level=warn \
        --display_error_number -Z1672 -Z298 -Z295 -X4856 -Z78 -X947 -Z3535 \
        -X3536 -Z479 -Z1250 -X3362 -X2867 -X2869 -X2868 -X4166 --long_long \
        -Z1208 -Z445 -X777 -Z1526 -X1312 -cpu=rh850g3k -Z942 -Z941 -Z1254 \
        -Z1354 -X1271 -Z1682 -X857 -Z4145 -Z4601 -Z4423 -Z4839 -Z4881 -Z4882 \
        -Z1106 -X1264 -X1558 -Z1562 -Z1563 -Z3978 -Z538 -Z1585 -X529 -X1752 \
        -Z3233 -Z4293 -X509 -Z3909 -Z4129 -Z4130 -Z4895 -X4989 -X5098 -X5099 \
        -Z5018 -X4995 --option=142 -OM --option=87 --option=88 \
        -D__PROTOTYPES__ -D__STDC__=0 -D__STDC_HOSTED__=1 \
        -D__STDC_VERSION__=199409L -D__ATTRIBUTES -D__EDG__ -D__ghs -D__ghs__ \
        -D__SoftwareFloat -D__SoftwareFloat__ -D__SoftwareDouble \
        -D__SoftwareDouble__ -D__ghs_asm=2 -D__ELF -D__ELF__ \
        -D__CORE_V850E3V5__ -D__CORE_V850E2V3__ -D__CORE_V850E2R__ \
        -D__CORE_V850E2__ -D__CORE_V850E__ -D__CORE_V850__ -D__V850E \
        -D__V850E__ -D__V850E2 -D__V850E2__ -D__V850E2R -D__V850E2R__ \
        -D__V850E2RV3 -D__V850E2RV3__ -D__V850E2V3 -D__V850E2V3__ -D__V850E3 \
        -D__V850E3__ -D__V850E3V5 -D__V850E3V5__ -D__RH850 -D__RH850__ \
        -D__V850 -D__V850__ -D__RH850G3K__ -D__RH850G3K \
        -D__V800_registermode=32 -D__V800_registermode__=32 \
        -D__RH850_FPU_VERSION=3 -D__RH850_FPU_VERSION__=3 -D__V800 -D__V800__ \
        -D__v850 -D__v851__ -D__v850e__ -D__ghs_alignment=8 \
        -D__ghs_max_pack_value=8 -D__ghs_sda -D__ghs_zda -D__LittleEndian \
        -D__LittleEndian__ -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__ -D__IeeeFloat -D__IeeeFloat__ \
        -D__Char_Is_Signed__ -D__SIGNED_CHARS__ -D__Ptr_Is_Unsigned__ \
        -D__Field_Is_Signed__ -D__Enum_Field_Is_Signed__ -D__Int_Is_32 \
        -D__Long_Is_32 -D__LL_Is_64 -D__Ptr_Is_32 -D__CHAR_BIT=8 \
        -D__SHRT_BIT=16 -D__INT_BIT=32 -D__LONG_BIT=32 -D__WCHAR_BIT=32 \
        -D__TIME_T_BIT=32 -D__PTR_BIT=32 -D__FUNCPTR_BIT=32 -D__TIME_T_BIT=32 \
        -D__LL_BIT=64 -D__LLONG_BIT=64 -D__MAX_BIT=64 -D__LDBL_BIT=64 \
        -D__LDBL_SIZE=8 -D__REG_BIT=32 -D__FREG_BIT=32 -D__Reg_Is_32 \
        -D__WChar_Is_Signed__ -D__WChar_Is_Long__ \
        -D__GHS_Inline_String_Functions -D__GHS_Inline_Memory_Functions \
        -D__ghs_board_is_v800_generic -Idevice \
        -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\include\v800 -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\ansi -X1189 \
        -X1610 -X1116 -X1875 -X614 -D__ASSEMBLER__ -D__LANGUAGE_ASM \
        -D__LANGUAGE_ASM__ -E --option=98 --option=214 \
        --gh_oname=output\objects\dr7f701587_startup.o -M \
        --gh_md=output\objects\dr7f701587_startup.d --option=-62 -o \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00007rg1.s \
        device\dr7f701587_startup.850
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ease850.exe -w -elf -b0 -Idevice \
        -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850 -cg_underscore -cpu=rh850g3k -nofpu \
        -no_v850_simd -source=device\dr7f701587_startup.850 \
        --gh_oname=output\objects\dr7f701587_startup.o \
        --gh_md_append=output\objects\dr7f701587_startup.d -o \
        output\objects\gh_00007rg1.o -list=output\list\dr7f701587_startup.lst \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00007rg1.s
move output\objects\gh_00007rg1.o output\objects\dr7f701587_startup.o
rm -f C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00007rg1.s
Compiling SchM_Port.c because SchM_Port.o does not exist
Output from Compiling App_PORT_F1K_Sample.c:
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ecom800.exe --option=70 -Z848 -X4593 -Z752 -X722 -X682 \
        -X735 -X780 -Z1715 -X1165 --c --gnu=safe -Z1835 --diag_warning=223 \
        --diag_warning=1547,1791 -Z1840 --config \
        t,t,l,,2,4,4,8,4,2,4,4,8,4,8,32,4,8,8,4,8,8,-1,f,f,-1,i,ui,1,f,t,1,1,8,1,8,72,4,6,f,3,0,0 \
        --option=27 --option=30 --option=40 --option=147 --gnu_version=40300 \
       SAME AS PREVIOUS (Removed because body limit caraccters are 40000)

        source\App_PORT_F1K_Sample.c
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ease850.exe -w -elf -b0 -Idevice \
        -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850 -cg_underscore -cpu=rh850g3k -nofpu \
        -no_v850_simd -nomacro \
        -patch_dbo=C:\GHS_Projects\output\objects\App_PORT_F1K_Sample.dbo \
        -source=App_PORT_F1K_Sample.c -o output\objects\gh_00004j81.o \
        -list=output\list\App_PORT_F1K_Sample.lst \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00004j81.s
move output\objects\gh_00004j81.o output\objects\App_PORT_F1K_Sample.o
rm -f C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00004j81.s
Output from Compiling SchM_Port.c:
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ecom800.exe --option=70 -Z848 -X4593 -Z752 -X722 -X682 \
        -X735 -X780 -Z1715 -X1165 --c --gnu=safe -Z1835 --diag_warning=223 \
        --diag_warning=1547,1791 -Z1840 --config \
    t,t,l,,2,4,4,8,4,2,4,4,8,4,8,32,4,8,8,4,8,8,-1,f,f,-1,i,ui,1,f,t,1,1,8,1,8,72,4,6,f,3,0,0 \
        --option=27 --option=30 --option=40 --option=147 --gnu_version=40300 \
        -$ -X70 -X1532 -X1602 -X540 --option=124 --alternative_tokens \
        --ghs_xref=1 --diag_remark=667,1546 --pragma_diag_level=warn \
        --display_error_number -Z1672 -Z298 -Z295 -X4856 -Z78 -X947 -Z3535 \
        -X3536 -Z479 -Z1250 -X3362 -X2867 -X2869 -X2868 -X4166 --long_long \
        -Z1208 -Z445 -X777 -Z1526 -X1312 -cpu=rh850g3k -Z942 -Z941 -Z1254 \
        -Z1354 -X1271 -Z1682 -X857 -Z4145 -Z4601 -Z4423 -Z4839 -Z4881 -Z4882 \
        -Z1106 -X1264 -X1558 -Z1562 -Z1563 -Z3978 -Z538 -Z1585 -X529 -X1752 \
        -Z3233 -Z4293 -X509 -Z3909 -Z4129 -Z4130 -Z4895 -X4989 -X5098 -X5099 \
        -Z5018 -X4995 --option=142 -OM -D__PROTOTYPES__ -D__STDC__=0 \
        -D__STDC_HOSTED__=1 -D__STDC_VERSION__=199409L -D__ATTRIBUTES \
        -D__EDG__ -D__ghs -D__ghs__ -D__SoftwareFloat -D__SoftwareFloat__ \
        -D__SoftwareDouble -D__SoftwareDouble__ -D__ghs_asm=2 -D__ELF \
        -D__ELF__ -D__CORE_V850E3V5__ -D__CORE_V850E2V3__ -D__CORE_V850E2R__ \
        -D__CORE_V850E2__ -D__CORE_V850E__ -D__CORE_V850__ -D__V850E \
        -D__V850E__ -D__V850E2 -D__V850E2__ -D__V850E2R -D__V850E2R__ \
        -D__V850E2RV3 -D__V850E2RV3__ -D__V850E2V3 -D__V850E2V3__ -D__V850E3 \
        -D__V850E3__ -D__V850E3V5 -D__V850E3V5__ -D__RH850 -D__RH850__ \
        -D__V850 -D__V850__ -D__RH850G3K__ -D__RH850G3K \
        -D__V800_registermode=32 -D__V800_registermode__=32 \
        -D__RH850_FPU_VERSION=3 -D__RH850_FPU_VERSION__=3 -D__V800 -D__V800__ \
        -D__v850 -D__v851__ -D__v850e__ -D__ghs_alignment=8 \
        -D__ghs_max_pack_value=8 -D__ghs_sda -D__ghs_zda -D__LittleEndian \
        -D__LittleEndian__ -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__ -D__IeeeFloat -D__IeeeFloat__ \
        -D__Char_Is_Signed__ -D__SIGNED_CHARS__ -D__Ptr_Is_Unsigned__ \
        -D__Field_Is_Signed__ -D__Enum_Field_Is_Signed__ -D__Int_Is_32 \
        -D__Long_Is_32 -D__LL_Is_64 -D__Ptr_Is_32 -D__CHAR_BIT=8 \
        -D__SHRT_BIT=16 -D__INT_BIT=32 -D__LONG_BIT=32 -D__WCHAR_BIT=32 \
        -D__TIME_T_BIT=32 -D__PTR_BIT=32 -D__FUNCPTR_BIT=32 -D__TIME_T_BIT=32 \
        -D__LL_BIT=64 -D__LLONG_BIT=64 -D__MAX_BIT=64 -D__LDBL_BIT=64 \
        -D__LDBL_SIZE=8 -D__REG_BIT=32 -D__FREG_BIT=32 -D__Reg_Is_32 \
        -D__WChar_Is_Signed__ -D__WChar_Is_Long__ \
        -D__GHS_Inline_String_Functions -D__GHS_Inline_Memory_Functions \
        -D__ghs_board_is_v800_generic -Idevice \
        -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\include\v800 -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\ansi -g -X1361 \
        -X1189 -X1610 -X1936 -X1116 -X1875 -X614 -D__LANGUAGE_C \
        -D__LANGUAGE_C__ -M --output_dir output\objects \
        -sym=C:\GHS_Projects\output\objects\Dem.dbo \
        -M --gh_md=output\objects\Dem.d --gh_oname=output\objects\Dem.o \
        --gh_out C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00006681.s \
        source\Dem.c
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ease850.exe -w -elf -b0 -Idevice \
        -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850 -cg_underscore -cpu=rh850g3k -nofpu \
        -no_v850_simd -nomacro \
        -patch_dbo=C:\GHS_Projects\output\objects\Dem.dbo \
        -source=Dem.c -o output\objects\gh_00006681.o \
        -list=output\list\Dem.lst \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00006681.s
move output\objects\gh_00006681.o output\objects\Dem.o
rm -f C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00006681.s
Output from Compiling Port.c:
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ecom800.exe --option=70 -Z848 -X4593 -Z752 -X722 -X682 \
        -X735 -X780 -Z1715 -X1165 --c --gnu=safe -Z1835 --diag_warning=223 \
        --diag_warning=1547,1791 -Z1840 --config \
        t,t,l,,2,4,4,8,4,2,4,4,8,4,8,32,4,8,8,4,8,8,-1,f,f,-1,i,ui,1,f,t,1,1,8,1,8,72,4,6,f,3,0,0 \
        --option=27 --option=30 --option=40 --option=147 --gnu_version=40300 \
        -$ -X70 -X1532 -X1602 -X540 --option=124 --alternative_tokens \
        --ghs_xref=1 --diag_remark=667,1546 --pragma_diag_level=warn \
        --display_error_number -Z1672 -Z298 -Z295 -X4856 -Z78 -X947 -Z3535 \
        -X3536 -Z479 -Z1250 -X3362 -X2867 -X2869 -X2868 -X4166 --long_long \
        -Z1208 -Z445 -X777 -Z1526 -X1312 -cpu=rh850g3k -Z942 -Z941 -Z1254 \
        -Z1354 -X1271 -Z1682 -X857 -Z4145 -Z4601 -Z4423 -Z4839 -Z4881 -Z4882 \
        -Z1106 -X1264 -X1558 -Z1562 -Z1563 -Z3978 -Z538 -Z1585 -X529 -X1752 \
        -Z3233 -Z4293 -X509 -Z3909 -Z4129 -Z4130 -Z4895 -X4989 -X5098 -X5099 \
        -Z5018 -X4995 --option=142 -OM -D__PROTOTYPES__ -D__STDC__=0 \
        -D__STDC_HOSTED__=1 -D__STDC_VERSION__=199409L -D__ATTRIBUTES \
        -D__EDG__ -D__ghs -D__ghs__ -D__SoftwareFloat -D__SoftwareFloat__ \
        -D__SoftwareDouble -D__SoftwareDouble__ -D__ghs_asm=2 -D__ELF \
        -D__ELF__ -D__CORE_V850E3V5__ -D__CORE_V850E2V3__ -D__CORE_V850E2R__ \
        -D__CORE_V850E2__ -D__CORE_V850E__ -D__CORE_V850__ -D__V850E \
        -D__V850E__ -D__V850E2 -D__V850E2__ -D__V850E2R -D__V850E2R__ \
        -D__V850E2RV3 -D__V850E2RV3__ -D__V850E2V3 -D__V850E2V3__ -D__V850E3 \
        -D__V850E3__ -D__V850E3V5 -D__V850E3V5__ -D__RH850 -D__RH850__ \
        -D__V850 -D__V850__ -D__RH850G3K__ -D__RH850G3K \
        -D__V800_registermode=32 -D__V800_registermode__=32 \
        -D__RH850_FPU_VERSION=3 -D__RH850_FPU_VERSION__=3 -D__V800 -D__V800__ \
        -D__v850 -D__v851__ -D__v850e__ -D__ghs_alignment=8 \
        -D__ghs_max_pack_value=8 -D__ghs_sda -D__ghs_zda -D__LittleEndian \
        -D__LittleEndian__ -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__ -D__IeeeFloat -D__IeeeFloat__ \
        -D__Char_Is_Signed__ -D__SIGNED_CHARS__ -D__Ptr_Is_Unsigned__ \
        -D__Field_Is_Signed__ -D__Enum_Field_Is_Signed__ -D__Int_Is_32 \
        -D__Long_Is_32 -D__LL_Is_64 -D__Ptr_Is_32 -D__CHAR_BIT=8 \
        -D__SHRT_BIT=16 -D__INT_BIT=32 -D__LONG_BIT=32 -D__WCHAR_BIT=32 \
        -D__TIME_T_BIT=32 -D__PTR_BIT=32 -D__FUNCPTR_BIT=32 -D__TIME_T_BIT=32 \
        -D__LL_BIT=64 -D__LLONG_BIT=64 -D__MAX_BIT=64 -D__LDBL_BIT=64 \
        -D__LDBL_SIZE=8 -D__REG_BIT=32 -D__FREG_BIT=32 -D__Reg_Is_32 \
        -D__WChar_Is_Signed__ -D__WChar_Is_Long__ \
        -D__GHS_Inline_String_Functions -D__GHS_Inline_Memory_Functions \
        -D__ghs_board_is_v800_generic -Idevice \
        -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\include\v800 -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\ansi -g -X1361 \
        -X1189 -X1610 -X1936 -X1116 -X1875 -X614 -D__LANGUAGE_C \
        -D__LANGUAGE_C__ -M --output_dir output\objects \
        -sym=C:\GHS_Projects\output\objects\Port.dbo \
        -M --gh_md=output\objects\Port.d --gh_oname=output\objects\Port.o \
        --gh_out C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_000029s1.s \
        source\Port.c
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ease850.exe -w -elf -b0 -Idevice \
        -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850 -cg_underscore -cpu=rh850g3k -nofpu \
        -no_v850_simd -nomacro \
        -patch_dbo=C:\GHS_Projects\output\objects\Port.dbo \
        -source=Port.c -o output\objects\gh_000029s1.o \
        -list=output\list\Port.lst \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_000029s1.s
move output\objects\gh_000029s1.o output\objects\Port.o
rm -f C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_000029s1.s
Output from Compiling Port_Hardware.c:
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ecom800.exe --option=70 -Z848 -X4593 -Z752 -X722 -X682 \
        -X735 -X780 -Z1715 -X1165 --c --gnu=safe -Z1835 --diag_warning=223 \
        --diag_warning=1547,1791 -Z1840 --config \
        t,t,l,,2,4,4,8,4,2,4,4,8,4,8,32,4,8,8,4,8,8,-1,f,f,-1,i,ui,1,f,t,1,1,8,1,8,72,4,6,f,3,0,0 \
        --option=27 --option=30 --option=40 --option=147 --gnu_version=40300 \
        -$ -X70 -X1532 -X1602 -X540 --option=124 --alternative_tokens \
        SAME AS PREVIOUS (Removed because body limit caraccters are 40000)
        -D__WChar_Is_Signed__ -D__WChar_Is_Long__ \
        -D__GHS_Inline_String_Functions -D__GHS_Inline_Memory_Functions \
        -D__ghs_board_is_v800_generic -Idevice \
        -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\include\v800 -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\ansi -g -X1361 \
        -X1189 -X1610 -X1936 -X1116 -X1875 -X614 -D__LANGUAGE_C \
        -D__LANGUAGE_C__ -M --output_dir output\objects \
        -sym=C:\GHS_Projects\output\objects\Port_Hardware.dbo \
        -M --gh_md=output\objects\Port_Hardware.d \
        --gh_oname=output\objects\Port_Hardware.o --gh_out \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00007ns1.s \
        source\Port_Hardware.c
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ease850.exe -w -elf -b0 -Idevice \
        -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850 -cg_underscore -cpu=rh850g3k -nofpu \
        -no_v850_simd -nomacro \
        -patch_dbo=C:\GHS_Projects\output\objects\Port_Hardware.dbo \
        -source=Port_Hardware.c -o output\objects\gh_00007ns1.o \
        -list=output\list\Port_Hardware.lst \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00007ns1.s
move output\objects\gh_00007ns1.o output\objects\Port_Hardware.o
rm -f C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00007ns1.s
Output from Compiling Port_PBcfg.c:
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ecom800.exe --option=70 -Z848 -X4593 -Z752 -X722 -X682 \
        -X735 -X780 -Z1715 -X1165 --c --gnu=safe -Z1835 --diag_warning=223 \
        --diag_warning=1547,1791 -Z1840 --config \
        t,t,l,,2,4,4,8,4,2,4,4,8,4,8,32,4,8,8,4,8,8,-1,f,f,-1,i,ui,1,f,t,1,1,8,1,8,72,4,6,f,3,0,0 \
         SAME AS PREVIOUS (Removed because body limit caraccters are 40000)
        -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\include\v800 -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\ansi -g -X1361 \
        -X1189 -X1610 -X1936 -X1116 -X1875 -X614 -D__LANGUAGE_C \
        -D__LANGUAGE_C__ -M --output_dir output\objects \
        -sym=C:\GHS_Projects\output\objects\Port_PBcfg.dbo \
        -M --gh_md=output\objects\Port_PBcfg.d \
        --gh_oname=output\objects\Port_PBcfg.o --gh_out \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00004g41.s source\Port_PBcfg.c
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ease850.exe -w -elf -b0 -Idevice \
        -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850 -cg_underscore -cpu=rh850g3k -nofpu \
        -no_v850_simd -nomacro \
        -patch_dbo=C:\GHS_Projects\output\objects\Port_PBcfg.dbo \
        -source=Port_PBcfg.c -o output\objects\gh_00004g41.o \
        -list=output\list\Port_PBcfg.lst \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00004g41.s
move output\objects\gh_00004g41.o output\objects\Port_PBcfg.o
rm -f C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00004g41.s
Output from Compiling Port_Ram.c:
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ecom800.exe --option=70 -Z848 -X4593 -Z752 -X722 -X682 \
        -X735 -X780 -Z1715 -X1165 --c --gnu=safe -Z1835 --diag_warning=223 \
        --diag_warning=1547,1791 -Z1840 --config \
        t,t,l,,2,4,4,8,4,2,4,4,8,4,8,32,4,8,8,4,8,8,-1,f,f,-1,i,ui,1,f,t,1,1,8,1,8,72,4,6,f,3,0,0 \
        --option=27  
         SAME AS PREVIOUS (Removed because body limit caraccters are 40000)
        -X1189 -X1610 -X1936 -X1116 -X1875 -X614 -D__LANGUAGE_C \
        -D__LANGUAGE_C__ -M --output_dir output\objects \
        -sym=C:\GHS_Projects\output\objects\Port_Ram.dbo \
        -M --gh_md=output\objects\Port_Ram.d \
        --gh_oname=output\objects\Port_Ram.o --gh_out \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00007l81.s source\Port_Ram.c
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ease850.exe -w -elf -b0 -Idevice \
        -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850 -cg_underscore -cpu=rh850g3k -nofpu \
        -no_v850_simd -nomacro \
        -patch_dbo=C:\GHS_Projects\output\objects\Port_Ram.dbo \
        -source=Port_Ram.c -o output\objects\gh_00007l81.o \
        -list=output\list\Port_Ram.lst \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00007l81.s
move output\objects\gh_00007l81.o output\objects\Port_Ram.o
rm -f C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00007l81.s
Output from Compiling Port_Version.c:
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ecom800.exe --option=70 -Z848 -X4593 -Z752 -X722 -X682 \
        -X735 -X780 -Z1715 -X1165 --c --gnu=safe -Z1835 --diag_warning=223 \
        --diag_warning=1547,1791 -Z1840 --config \
        t,t,l,,2,4,4,8,4,2,4,4,8,4,8,32,4,8,8,4,8,8,-1,f,f,-1,i,ui,1,f,t,1,1,8,1,8,72,4,6,f,3,0,0 \
        --option=27 --option=30 --option=40 --option=147 --gnu_version=40300 \
        -$ -X70 -X1532 -X1602 -X540 --option=124 --alternative_tokens \
         SAME AS PREVIOUS (Removed because body limit caraccters are 40000)
        -X1189 -X1610 -X1936 -X1116 -X1875 -X614 -D__LANGUAGE_C \
        -D__LANGUAGE_C__ -M --output_dir output\objects \
        -sym=C:\GHS_Projects\output\objects\Port_Version.dbo \
        -M --gh_md=output\objects\Port_Version.d \
        --gh_oname=output\objects\Port_Version.o --gh_out \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_000063k1.s \
        source\Port_Version.c
C:\ghs\comp_201355\ease850.exe -w -elf -b0 -Idevice \
        -IC:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850 -cg_underscore -cpu=rh850g3k -nofpu \
        -no_v850_simd -nomacro \
        -patch_dbo=C:\GHS_Projects\output\objects\Port_Version.dbo \
        -source=Port_Version.c -o output\objects\gh_000063k1.o \
        -list=output\list\Port_Version.lst \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_000063k1.s
move output\objects\gh_000063k1.o output\objects\Port_Version.o
rm -f C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_000063k1.s
Linking example because it does not exist
Output from Linking example.gpj:
gmemfile: fatal: unable to open input file 'output/example'
Output from Linking example.gpj:
gsrec: fatal: unable to open input file 'output/example'
Output from Linking example.gpj:
gsrec: fatal: unable to open input file 'output/example'
Output from Linking example.gpj:
C:\ghs\comp_201355\elxr.exe -T device\dr7f701587.ld -map -Mxa -callgraph \
        -nochecksum -unweak=___gh_float_scanf -wchar_s32 -farcallpatch \
        -argcheck=none -Qn -e _RESET -LC:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850 \
        C:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850\crt0.o \
        output\objects\dr7f701587_startup.o \
        output\objects\App_PORT_F1K_Sample.o output\objects\Dem.o \
        output\objects\Port.o output\objects\Port_Hardware.o \
        output\objects\Port_PBcfg.o output\objects\Port_Ram.o \
        output\objects\Port_Version.o output\objects\SchM_Port.o -lmulti \
        -lfmalloc -lwchar_s32 -lansi -lwc_s32 -lmath_sf -lind_sf -lstartup \
        -lsys -larch -o output\example --gh_md=output\example.dep
C:\ghs\comp_201355\gnm.exe -s output\example > C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00003301.nm
C:\ghs\comp_201355\dblink.exe -dbopath=output\objects -a -nm=gnm \
        C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00003301.nm -o \
        output\example.dnm -top_project \
        C:\GHS_Projects\example.gpj \
        -Dscope.tools_dir=C:\ghs\comp_201355 \
        -Dscope.target=v800/generic/standalone -Dscope.processor=800 \
        -Dscope.cpuname=rh850g3k -Dscope.fputype=soft \
        -Dscope.deflibdir=C:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850 \
        C:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850\crt0.dbo \
        C:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850\libmulti.dba \
        C:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850\libfmalloc.dba \
        C:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850\libwchar_s32.dba \
        C:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850\libansi.dba \
        C:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850\libwc_s32.dba \
        C:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850\libmath_sf.dba \
        C:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850\libind_sf.dba \
        C:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850\libstartup.dba \
        C:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850\libsys.dba \
        C:\ghs\comp_201355\lib\rh850\libarch.dba
C:\ghs\comp_201355\gsize.exe -gcompare -table -commons output\example > output\example.siz
rm -f C:\Users\chfakht\AppData\Local\Temp\gh_00003301.nm
Error: build failed
Build failed (Mon Oct 24 09:10:45 2016)
```

**Update 2:**

I found this in a GHS manual but for arm where the same message error appear

> Customizing the Run-Time Environment Program Sections This section describes the special program sections that are created for and
>   maintained by the Green Hills run-time environment system (the
>   libraries libsys.a and libstartup.a and the module crt0.o). These
>   sections appear in all the default linker directives files provided
>   with your distribution, and their contents are generated
>   automatically, so you should not explicitly add to them: • .fixaddr,
>   .fixtype — These sections are created by the compiler. These two
>   sections contain information that enables the Green Hills startup code
>   to relocate PIC/PID initializers of data variables. The compiler
>   automatically generates data in the .fixaddr and .fixtype sections, if
>   needed, when using PIC and/or PID. The default Green Hills run-time
>   libraries may also already have information in these sections because
>   many of these libraries are always built with PIC and PID. These two
>   sections contain read-only data and can be placed in ROM. Failure to
>   include these sections in the linker directives file may cause them to
>   be added to the end of the section list by the Green Hills linker,
>   which can then emit the following warning message: [elxr] warning:
>   section .fixaddr from libsys.a(ind_crt1.o) isn’t included by the
>   section map (as .fixaddr); appending after last section add to section
>   map or use -append to append without warning If the program depends on
>   dynamic memory expanding past the end of the last specified section in
>   a section map, having sections appended to the section map might be
>   fatal because they can be overwritten. Therefore, these sections
>   should be included in section maps.

Is it related to the compiler itself ? or due to some options i have used ?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It's now been >5 years since I used MULTI so I don't know how much has changed... but do you have a .gpj file for your project? What happens if you add `-v` and/or `-#` to the compiler options in that file?

Comment: thanks @Quuxplusone yes i have .gpj file. I will add -v and -# and let you know by monday because i don't have access now to the license server.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I have updated the post with the log. Hope you can help with something or if not suggest where can i look for help.Many thanks

Comment: Are there explicit short calls in the code? Similar to `JMP rel8` or `JMP rel16` for x86? If so, then the label it tries to jump to or call was moved further away from the call site than the opcode allows. For instance, if the code has explicitly asked for a `JMP rel8` in x86, but the target label is more than -127/+128 addresses way, it won't work. The way the error message is worded suggests to me that something like this might be the problem.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Hi, What do you mean by short calls ?. I'm using a startup code in assembly (given by supplier) and also a lot of code is auto generated. The MCU is a Renesas RH850/F1K . If you have any comments or suggestions to give me , feel free, i really appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: I have just added a description of the error found in a GHS manual for arm.

Comment: Sorry, I have no knowledge of greenhils or ghs, it was just the wording of the error message that triggered that comment. Whether it fits or not I cannot say, nor what else could be the problem. I just know that in some languages you can say "call this label, and make it a short call" and "short call" here means a relative address, that is that instead of saying "call address 0x12345678" you get "call address +0x200" where "+0x200" is relative to where the call instruction is, and "short" means "make that relative number a 16-bit value".

Comment: If the actual label, when linking, is placed further away from the call instruction than can fit into a 16-bit number you can get a similar error message.

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788188/greenhills-small-data-area-overflow

Comment: Yes, i'm waiting for @Quuxplusone if he can remember something. I see the same +0x01c maybe some RAM area is full and the compiler cannot write more data. From what you said it's a short call  .. However can you suggest a workaround or a solution ? But anyway thanks for help.